# Why can't I travel between these systems with wavy connecting lines?

Tags: endless-space

I'm playing my first game of Endless Space, and after exploring 4 or 5 systems around my home system, I seem to be out of places to go. I do see two other systems, but my scout refuses to travel to them. They've got wavy lines connecting them instead of the usual solid ones, so maybe it means I need some sort of special tech to be able to travel there?

[image]

What do I need to do to be able to explore those systems?

Comment: If anyone wants to say "thanks" or "me too!" or similar, please register with this forum and upvote the question and/or answer!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After playing a bit longer and unlocking some techs, I was able to answer this myself. It looks like those wavy lines represent wormholes, and you simply need the Applied Casimir Effect technology to traverse them.

[image]

After unlocking this tech, the wavy lines connecting the systems turned green and I was able to send my ships down them.

Comment: I had this same issue. Was not expecting "Worm Holes" to look like space tornadoes.

Comment: Thanks man for your answer, had the same problem, after googling it I found your post. You probably helped quite a bunch of people by creating this post. Thanks again.